# What is the good ruby world-wide programming competition other than Rails rumble?

Tags: ruby

Please name one or more ruby world-wide programming competitions other than rails rumble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rubyquiz.com

It is not a programming competition per say but quiet close.